# parsing JSON in jquery returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically my goal is to get all the json values into javascript / jquery variable so that i can show them on my html input fields. I am beginner in javascript so i cannot identify what i am doing wrong. Below is my function

```
 // Update existing customers 
                $("#records").on('click', ".update", function() {
                    var data = $(this).attr('id');
                    var object = {};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "viewcustomers.php",
                        data: {update: data},
                        success: function(response) {
<!--                           console.log(response);-->
                           object = $.parseJSON(response);
                           console.log(object.name);
```

So when i run this function i get a json response in my success: like below

```
"[{"id":"1","name":"ali","cnic":"01","address":"nipa","email":"301","phone":"luxairy "}]"
```

Now as per my understanding i tried to parse the response via jquery and take it in object.
But when i am trying to console.log name or any other value its saying undefined.

Please help me understanding what i am doing wrong. Thank you.
            }
                    });

Comment: `[]` indicates that you get an array (with 1 element in this exact case), as you can see here - http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 4):

You have to get object from array, the square brackets `[]` in begining and end make the the json object an array of objects. You need to use array indexer notation. Remember it is zero-index that means first element is at `zero` index.

*Change*

```
object.name
```

*To*

```
object[0].name
```

**Edit**, based on commments, to iterate through object array you can use loop.

```
for(i=0; i < object.length; i++) 
    console.log(object[i].name);
```

Comment: [0] means ? is it necessary to have a numeric index ?

Comment: It is array indexer notation. Remember it is zero-index that means first element is at `zero` index.

Comment: worked thank you so much ... it means if i have more rows in JSON so i will have to use indexes right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use loop to iterate through them

Comment: for(i=0; i < object.length; i++) console.log(object[i].name);